# Python 3 PyPy implementation?

Tags: python

I would like to use the PyPy Python JIT Implementation using Python 3. However I can only seem to install it using Python 2. Is there even an experimental implementation of PyPy for Python 3 I can try out? Are there plans to port it to Python 3? Or do I need to keep using Python 2 for it? I've gotten quite accustomed to Python 3 and I would like to use it as much as possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because PSE is not a support site for third party tools.

Comment: [PyPy3 2.4.0 release announcement](http://morepypy.blogspot.fr/2014/10/pypy3-240-released.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My friend told me that there isn't a solution for this problem. You will propably have to stick with python 2 for now unless you want to implement it yourself.